# Python: Parsing a complex string into usable data for analysis

Tags: python, string, parsing, text

Is it possible to parse the below string, using Python, or convert it into another data structure so that each element can be accessed for analysis?

This is an example line from a large text file where each line has the same format.

```
string = ["('a', '1')", "('b', '2')"]
```

Comment: Considering that the data you've given us looks regular (which really is the key) the answer is most likely yes. But it's impossible to say without knowing what data format you would like. can you give us an example of what you would want outputted as well as what would be inputted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to convert the tuple-strings to tuples, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in string]
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]
```

Use of `ast.literal_eval` rather than `eval` is encouraged as it is considered safer: it does not execute *all* strings of Python code, only literal expressions (no variables, no function calls).

You can then access the elements of the tuples using Python's slice/index notation, or convert to an alternative data structure, e.g. a dictionary:

```
>>> dict([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in string])
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) within a list comprehension :

```
>>> s= ["('a', '1')", "('b', '2')"]
>>> import ast
>>> [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in s]
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]
```

> `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display.

Also as your elements are string you can use `regex` to parse your list elemets :

```
>>> import re
>>> a=[re.findall(r"'(.*?)'",i) for i in s]
>>> a
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2']]
```

The pattern `'(.*?)'` will matched anything between 2 one quote!

Answer (score 1):

```
[eval(s) for s in string]
```

This will convert your list of strings to a list of tuples

---

Edit: The other answers suggested using literal_eval instead of eval. If your data is coming from an untrusted source you'll want to do that. [literal_eval doc link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)